# Inline JS onclick Function Call Error

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make each button call a function called `sDM()` and input a different code but whenever I do this, I get:

ReferenceError: sDM is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

```
<button onclick="sDM(38)" style="width: 100%">&#8593;</button>
<br>
<button onclick="sDM(37)"  style="width: 47%">&#8592;</button>&nbsp;
<button onclick="sDM(39)" style="width: 47%">&#8594;</button>
<br>
<button onclick="sDM(40)" style="width: 100%">&#8595;</button>
```

My function:

```
  function sDM (dN) {
           snake.setDirection(directions[dN])
         }
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(could be)Looks like that your javascript is loaded before your html. Please insert your javascript inside one of those listeners

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function( event ) {
    // Do something
});
```

or

```
window.addEventListener( 'load', function( event ) {
    // Do something
});
```

Here's the [explanation](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded).